# Suggest a domain name

Tags: discussion, essential-meta-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/write-and-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name bicycles.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Post your ideas for a dot-com domain name for this website

Please follow these guidelines:

- Check to see if the domain is taken
  before making the name
  suggestion. Squatted and taken names,
  however clever, are not helpful. You
  can use [whois.net](http://www.whois.net/) to check
  availability.
- Post one domain per answer. This
  makes the voting process much easier.
  If domains are very similar (e.g.
  "game" and "games"), they can be in
  the same answer.
- Make sure the domain wasn't already
  suggested. To search within this
  question, use a search query such as:
  inquestion:1 "example.com" replacing
  example.com with the domain to search
  for

---

From "[Stack Exchange FAQ: Domain Names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/)":

1. Please don’t think that it’s necessary to use a domain name that reflects something going wrong. We picked the name “Stack Overflow” because it has some meaning for real programmers, not because it reflected a bug or problem. “Super User” is just as good a name. I get depressed by all these suggestions of “BurntChicken.com”, “LostYarmulke.com”, and “FallenArches.com” (for former owners of McDonald’s franchises, of course).
2. Look for jargon that has meaning to the group of people you want to attract. Insider jargon is the duck call of insiders. Look at me! If I can say “contributory negligence,” I must be a real lawyer!
3. .coms are a million times better than other TLDs.
4. A domain name should be readable over the phone. Even on AT&T Wireless. Tricky spellings are always a bad idea. Similarly, dashes reek of desperation.
5. Long names are not the end of the world. Using two or three words (or a couple of digits) is a good way to find available domains.

(Or see section 4 on [our own meta FAQ](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).)

---

Let's try to brainstorm for some concise, bicycle-related and easily identifiable jargon per Domain Name FAQ #2. If we use a word (or words) unique to bicycling, we'll more likely be able to secure a .com domain name without paying a fortune.

Similarly, we should avoid very common terminology (Bike/Cycle/Cyclist/Bicycle) and terminology not specific to bicycling (Rider/Wheel/Velocity/Tire/Chain).

---

Finally, when posting a new suggestion, please use this format:

```
**FooBar.com** - ([Not Registered][1])

  [1]: http://www.whois.net/whois/foobar.com
```

Comment: It may be a while before anyone has a suggestion. Soon, I hope!

Comment: Ahahaha! Look who has `cyclingquestions.com`: The primary nameserver is `NS5.EXPERTS-EXCHANGE.COM` (not 100% proof but a pretty strong indication)

Comment: Unfortunately www.experts-exchange.com is an entirely different website than www.stackexchange.com

Comment: C'mon, we need more names! Are we gonna get stick with something boring like [BikeQuery.com](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name/14#14)? (My suggestion, yeah.)

Comment: @Dustin yes, that was [kind of my point](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/whos-your-arch-enemy.html).

Comment: @Pekka Woosh, right over my head. I thought you had thought someone here had pre-registered it. Cheers!

Comment: Should people just vote for the one they like, or upvote stuff we like and downvote stuff we dislike?

Comment: normally people seem to just upvote things they like, downvoting seems a bit useless in this context (unless the suggestion would need flagged)

Comment: Agreed -- those who are downvoting should instead comment on why a particular suggestion is not preferable.

Comment: http://cycling-exchange.com/ is already a (old) stack exchange site, I could possibly transfer the domain, if it's an acceptable domain name of course...

Comment: @mxmissie: If it get a lot of votes, sure!

Answer (score 11):

**CycleQuery.com** - ([Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/cycleQuery.com) by [Stack Overflow](http://who.godaddy.com/WhoIs.aspx?domain=cyclequery.com))

"Cycle" is short and works for unicycles, recumbent trikes, etc...

Comment: This is my favorite so far.

Comment: Also available are CyclingQueries.com -- [not taken](http://www.whois.net/whois/CyclingQueries.com) -- as well as BiyclingQueries.com -- [also not taken](http://www.whois.net/whois/BiyclingQueries.com).

Comment: @neilfein That may be because 'BiyclingQueries.com' is misspelled. =]

Comment: Other variations:  VeloQuery.com, CycleQA.com, VeloQA.com (all not taken)

Comment: Hate the word query

Comment: @Joe: I agree, the word "query" is pretty clinical.

Comment: @Joe, @neilfein: This one was originally my suggestion, but I don't like it much; too dry, too clinical, too straight to the point, too  much problem, not enough solution.  (CycleAnswers would be more solution oriented, but still too dry and clinical)

Comment: It looks like this is taken now; did someone here register this?

Comment: @neilfein: It's registered to "Stack Overflow Internet Services" with kyle@stackoverflow.com as the contact, so I think we're fine...

Comment: -1 Sorry, just not down with having to type [anything]query.com  (and this is coming from a programmer)

Answer (score 9):

**GreasyHands.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/greasyhands.com))

Is avaliable. It suggests mechanical whatsits, but it's memorable.

Comment: It could apply to repairing cars, or entirely different areas, as well... But it sounds nice, and everybody dealing with bikes knows what it feels like. I like it. +1

Answer (score 4):

**BrazeOns.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/brazeons.com))

Braze-ons are basically anything permanently attached to the frame. Brazing is a process halfway between soldering and welding that would be used to attach those on steel frames, but the term is used however the bits are attached. Examples: water bottle cage mounts, cable carriers/guides/stops, etc.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braze-on

Comment: Braze-Ons.com is also available ...

Comment: I have no idea what the word stands for, but it is short and sounds good. As a con, if transmitted over the phone, there are various ways of writing this: brazons.com braisons.com ....

Comment: @Pekka: braze-ons are any of the little holes, flanges, etc that are permanently attached to the frame.

Comment: I like this -- It's definitely cycle-jargon, it's specifically referential to bicycles, it's short, and braze-ons are awesome.

Comment: I think this will be quite confusing for any novice cyclist.

Comment: Unfortunately, could also be confused with BraZeons.com easily, which sounds like it could be a religious ritual involving boiling water and an undergarment...  Poor speakability, too: "BraiseOns", "BraysOns"...   Too bad, because Braze-ons really resonate more for me than "Cycle Query" or greasy hands...

Answer (score 4):

**GlueAndPatch.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/glueandpatch.com)), or
**PatchAndGlue.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/patchandglue.com))

Patching a flat is one of the very first things a amateur cyclist learns and is symblomatic of increased bicycle knowledge. The first makes procedural sense, but I think the second sounds a little bit better to the ear.

Answer (score 4):

**CrankPuller.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/crankpuller.com))

As in the tool.

Comment: I like it, but it might be a bit of an obscure reference for average bicyclists who've never seen one.

Comment: Was looking for an insider term that wasn't registered yet still familiar enough.  Sadly most terms are already registered, but at least this one includes "crank" which practically screams "cycling" to me.  ChainWhipped.com (but not chainwhip.com) is also available but reads slightly wrong...

Comment: Mmm, not bad. It's a little esoteric (I didn't know what the cranks were until I'd been seriously cycling for a while) but it's easy to read, easy to say over the phone, and memorable. It's a little too techie, but not too much. This gets my vote!

Comment: This is my current favorite: memorable, easy to say over the phone, a bit jargony/techie (which seems in line with the other stackexchange site names)

Comment: Sounds like a porn site's name...

Answer (score 3):

**CycleWhat.com** ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/cyclewhat.com))

Similar to CycleQuery but with a bit of whimsy in it. It's also, I think, more memorable and opens up a lot of site design possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

**BikeQuery.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/BikeQuery.com))

Comment: "Bike" could be confused with the motorized (motorcycle) type...

Comment: Yeah, but "BicycleQuery.com" is clumsy. One of the biggest forums for bicycles on the net is bikeforums, and they seem to be doing fine. BicycleQuery [is available](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name/25#25) though.

Comment: My concern with this one is speak-ability. "BikeQuery.com" could easily be confused for "BikeWeary" or "BikeEarry"

Answer (score 2):

**LikeBikes.com** - ([Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/Likebikes.com))

For sale. No price specified, .org, .net are unregistered

Answer (score 2):

**MilesPerBurger.com**

Thinking more of a theme here, but I don't have a good suggestion. Bikes are basically the most efficient means of transportation around. ([Bike performance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_performance) article on wikipedia) Most of us, whether racers, commuters, tourers, etc all know and love this aspect.

So perhaps something along those lines. themostefficientmachine.com is a heck of a mouthful and hard to spell, so it is terrible.

Just wanted to put the idea out there.

Comment: How about GetOffTheDamnCouch.com? :)

Comment: ZeroPerGallon.com is already taken.  :)

Comment: ZeroPerLitre.com is available!

Comment: I think infinite MPG makes more sense than zero MPG, don't you? Unfortunately, it's taken. =]

Answer (score 2):

**EccentricDropout.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/eccentricdropout.com))

Answer (score 2):

**VeloTribe.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/velotribe.com))

Answer (score 2):

**PedalPower.com** - [Squatted](http://www.whois.net/whois/pedalpower.com)

Answer (score 1):

**Cyclist.com** - ([Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/cyclist.com))

For sale (but probably beyond any sane price range - just adding for completeness)

Answer (score 1):

**TrainedWheels.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/trainedwheels.com))

Comment: Not my favorite, but it's at least an interesting name.

Answer (score 1):

**TacoedWheel.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/tacoedwheel.com))

Answer (score 1):

**HeadsetWrench.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/headsetwrench.com))

Answer (score 1):

**Cycling-Exchange.com** - (Registered)

Could possibly transfer. The dash probably kills this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**boneshaker.com** - ([Squatted - for sale](http://www.whois.net/whois/boneshaker.com))

Boneshaker (or "bone-shaker") is a name used from about 1869 up to the present time, to refer to the first type of true bicycle with pedals, which was called "velocipede" (from the Latin for "fast foot") by its manufacturers. "Boneshaker" refers to the extremely uncomfortable ride, which was caused by the stiff wrought-iron frame and wooden wheels surrounded by tires made of iron.<sup>[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boneshaker)</sup>

Comment: I'd upvote this if it were available. Unless by "squatted" you mean that you have it?

Answer (score 1):

**BentDerailer.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/bentderailleur.com))

**BentDerailleur.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/bentderailleur.com))

You'd really need to get both, since nobody can agree on whether the second word is english or french.

Answer (score 1):

**RideNuts.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/ridnuts.com))

Triple meaning:

- The nuts on your ride/bicycle wheels
- To ride your bicycle in a crazy excited manner
- People who are enthusiastic about bicycles

Easy to remember and easy to say to someone without having to explain or spell.

CycleNuts, BicycleNuts, BikeNuts and VeloNuts are all taken :(

Answer (score -1):

**BikeLove.com** - ([Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/bikelove.com))

My personal favourite:

- It's easy to pronounce across the globe, also on the phone
- It works for all audiences - casual bicyclists, sportspeople, professionals
- It works because person/bike is almost always an 1:1 relationship, and it reflects on the various depths in which one can be attached to their ride - from "you really should give your bike more love" to "I sleep next to mine"

Of course, it's already taken in all relevant TLDs and would have to be bought.

Comment: Are you thinking of this: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1567410/Man-who-had-sex-with-bike-in-court.html

Comment: @Tom ahahahahahahahaha!

Answer (score -1):

**HammeredVelo.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/HammeredVelo.com))

Velo is french for cycle, reminiscent of the old "velocipede" word for cycles that used to be used in english. A hammered velo could be one that needs fixing, or it could be one that got passed by somebody going extra fast, since racers passing somebody are "dropping the hammer".

Answer (score -1):

**BikeStuds.com** - [(Not Registered)](http://www.whois.net/whois/bikestuds.com)

Comment: As in winter riding? I'd sooner go with ChainWhipped.com. :)

Answer (score -2):

**TheThirdPoliceman.com** - [Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/TheThirdPoliceman.com)

Not a bicycle jargon reference, but a literary one - [The Third Policeman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Policeman) is a comic novel featuring Irish Policemen obsessed with their bikes.

I don't expect too many people to have heard of it, but does it trigger any suggestions for bicycles featuring prominently in popular media that would be well known?

Comment: Flann O'Brien, I'd forgotten about him. I remember reading An Béal Bocht about 20 years ago, fantastic! Although technically that's by him under a different  pen name. I think the reference might be lost on most people unfortunately.

Comment: [The Third Policeman preview at Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=q5fTaKax_hQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=The+Third+Policeman&hl=en&ei=sYSfTJSqD4KC8gaoq8H9DA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) - looks like fun!

Answer (score -2):

**WellBoiledIcicle.com** - ([Not Registered](http://www.whois.net/whois/wellboiledicicle.com))