# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/suggest-a-domain-name).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.
- [QBP](http://www.qbp.com/): QBP is the shop behind America’s bicycle shops.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.
- [Trek](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/company/believe/): We believe in bikes.
- [Bike Friday](http://www.bikefriday.com/): Performance that packs.
- [Co-Motion Cycles](http://co-motion.com/): American made, Oregon made, handmade.
- [League of American Bicycles](http://www.bikeleague.org/): Working for a Bicycle Friendly America.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: Were nearing the end of the standard beta period. I suspect we'll be in beta for a while longer while we build a user base, but we need to get serious about this elevator pitch. anyone have any more ideas?

Comment: Now that warmer weather in the northern hemisphere is around the corner, activity here is starting to pick up. Any additional thoughts on this, anyone?

Answer (score 5):

Bicycles: The answer to so many questions.

Answer (score 4):

How about a pun based on "geared", reflecting the definitions of:-

- A toothed machine part as found on a bike,
- Clothing and accessories,
- To adjust or adapt so as to make suitable

Some suggestions:

**Answers geared for cyclists.**

**Geared for Bikes.**

(Feel free to edit with a better options along this line).

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [this Zen joke](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/whats-your-best-bicycle-joke/1335#1335), I propose the following tagline:

> Why do we ride our bicycles?
>
> We ride our bicycles to ride our bicycles.

... which might be a bit to circular, meta, or Zen to work well as a tagline.

Answer (score 3):

Cyclists have a right to the road too, you  noisy polluting inconsiderate maniacs.

[image]

Perhaps a little long ?

Comment: I suspect that "I hope gas goes up to eight bucks a gallon" wouldn't go over well with some people, either...  ;)

Comment: Yeah, but awesome.

Comment: @freiheit - unless you live in the UK where you hope it comes down to $8/gallon

Comment: let's go with "I hope gas goes up to 100 bucks a gallon you inconsiderate maniacs!"

Answer (score 3):

To misquote George Orwell "Two wheels good - four wheels bad" ?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ragingcyclepath.com/ -

Registered for this site (if needed) along with common similar TLDs

Tagline:

"Ride your bike, or we'll kill you."   - (kidding)

or more realistic:

Nuts (and bolts) for bikes.

or

Nuts (and bolts) for bikers.

[image: Logo Submission]

**EDIT: If you like the graphic, but not the url or tagline, feel free to modify text, but link back here, please.**

Comment: That's quite nice, but it does make this sound like a bike maintenance site. I particularly like the graphic; did you design that? Maybe we can start looking into tee-shirts.

Comment: We probably won't be getting out own domain, although that one is pretty cool.

Comment: I did do the graphic. Why do you say we won't get our own domain? Based on traffic, or something?

Comment: It's not a traffic thing, they seem to want to stick with [foo].stackexchange.com domains. A few sites have exceptions, though. (We are a pretty low-traffic site, but slowly and steadily increasing.) I *really* like this graphic.

Comment: Thanks. Me, too. I was going for something that tied the tech aspects that are somewhat necessary, and can be fun if you get into it, to the more relaxed and prosaic "just ride" idea. Obviously, whatever tagline is eventually decided on can be included in place of current text. As for the domain, I think it would be good if we have something more attention grabby than bicycles.se, although I don't mind the .se extension. Is it possible technically to use .se  rather than stackexchange? For URL length? That's mt main bug with foo.stackexchange.com urls...

Comment: re:Using se - Since Stack Exchange doesn't own se.com, probably not.

Comment: The Stack Exchange team has a designer, who'll poke around and look at user suggestions (like this) and use these elements for a final design. I think this one will allow for many different unified elements.

Comment: I was trying for a similar vein for the tagline.. We're nuts about bikes, plus you can find all you need to know here too (nuts and bolts).  I can always use that url for a blog or something...

Comment: Sticking the .stackexchange.com is because that gives all the sites better Google ranking; switching to our own domain would get us much lower down on the Google search results pages.

Comment: ".se" is the domain for the country of Sweden. When you see short two-letter code domains like that used for things outside the country, it's typically a small poor country with little internet presence that's willing to sell off bits of their country domain. (.to is Tonga for instance)

Comment: I was more on the bikes.se.com idea...

Comment: +1 for "Nuts (and bolts) for bikes." As I read it, "nuts" refers to general enthusiasm for cycling, and "bolts" refers to maintenance. Together, they represent the essence of the site.

Answer (score 2):

- We know bicycles

Answer (score 2):

I don't have anything specific, but I keep mulling about a stack o' bikes. (This is a CW answer, please edit if you can refine this.)

Comment: I was trying to picture how you stack bicycles, then remembered this site from my daily commute: [Bicycle Obelisk](http://www.odditycentral.com/pics/cyckisk-the-bicycle-obelisk-of-santa-rosa.html)

Comment: @freiheit - Stacking our bikes to the moon! (Hey, I like that.)

Answer (score 2):

"On your bike" -- being that that's a colloquial expression (at least in England and Canada, maybe other countries too), punning with "On" meaning "About" or "On the topic of".

Or maybe "On your bikes" (plural), being that it's a community.

Comment: I used "On yer bike" on a poster to promote a cycling event recently :)

Answer (score 2):

"It is not about the bike? Oh, but it is."

Mod this entry down immediately, but someone has to reference Lance Armstrong's book.

Comment: The sequel: "Yes, it is."

Comment: Q. It's not about the bike? A. Yes, it is! (In Q+A format.)

Comment: Perhaps this suggestion needs to be changed to "Actually it's about the drugs"?

Answer (score 1):

Bicycle questions answered by bicycle geeks.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering how to reinvent the wheel?

*Implied:* Well, visit us then!

Answer (score 0):

Cranking out great answers to cycling questions.

Answer (score -1):

- Bicycles? Let me tell you about bicycles ...

Comment: That's more appropriate for a forum, where there's a conversational tone. (It's funny!)