# Who wants water bottles? Who has a catchy tagline? (UPDATE! - New Bottle Design, Art)

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange will soon be shipping custom water bottles to moderators and users with sufficient reputation.

But that's not all.

[image]
We haven't yet finalized the design for the bottles, in particular, the tagline printed for all to see while you proudly ride, repair or rehydrate.

We are looking for a phrase or two that is **short**, **catchy**, **bike-centric**, and **in-line with the philosophy of Stack Exchange**. The tagline should say, in some way, that you can ask your bike questions or offer your bike wisdom here.

Please provide your ideas as an answer to this meta post. Users who provide ideas used in the final design will receive a free Stack water bottle, of course.

What ya got?

**UPDATE:**

Since there's considerable disagreement on messaging, here's a message-free prototype:

[image]

Here's the art we're working with:

[image]

Any suggested improvements? Chime in and we'll settle on a final bottle design that the mods OK next week.

Also, what volume do you prefer: 22 oz. (top) or 26 oz.?

Comment: See also: [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/144/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

Comment: @Sam - Any chance we can get the night cyclist from Meta on the other side of the water bottle? (Flip back and forth from meta to the main site while watching the cyclist and you'll see why; I imagine rotating the bottle from front to back would give one a similar "animatic".)

Comment: Great idea Neil. I'm going to try to make that happen.

Comment: I *think* that the 22oz. bottles will fit in most bottle cages. I have some of both sizes, and the 24oz one is too tall to fit on a frame's secondary cage. (That's the one on [the seat tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_frame#Seat_tube).)

Comment: Different people are going to prefer one size or the other. The smaller size is probably the right option, since that will work for everybody. (some frame designs really don't allow those larger bottles)

Comment: who wants water bottles?  me me me!

Answer (score 6):

I quite like [Anthony K's proposal](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline/170#170) in the original Elevator Pitch thread:

### Bicycles: The answer to so many questions.

Comment: Not sure about this one, it needs more work to be an advertising-industry-grade tag line. The premise is good but the plural bicycles does not yet work with the singular 'answer' for me.

Comment: It could be singular. A bicycle: the answer to so many questions.

Comment: ʍǝɥʇɐɯ, Stephen - This answer is CW, go ahead and make changes if you like.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

**Thirst For Knowledge**

You could also put a "hydration" tag on the bottle :-)

Comment: Actually, I kinda like the idea of just putting the [tag:hydration] tag on the bottle. Although this slogan isn't bad!

Comment: I do like it, but only for the water bottle: not for the web site.

Answer (score 4):

Let's go for something a little more... provocative?

Maybe it isn't necessary that we get the Q/A-concept across--this isn't a final slogan for the site, just a catchy phrase for a slick water bottle. I think it's most important that we pique interest in those who don't know what SE is.

A few ideas:

Slake your face.
FACE FUEL
BRAIN GREASE
Ride hard. Never hit a paywall.
Never bonk.
A bike lane for your brain.
The superhighway's bike lane.

Keep em coming! Let's try to settle on something by the end of this week.

Comment: Well, then here's a couple suggestions from our [Elevator Pitch](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/144/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline/239#239) thread: "Cyclists have a right to the road too, you noisy polluting inconsiderate maniacs.", "I hope gas goes up to twenty bucks a gallon"

Comment: lol, I do like "I hope gas goes up to twenty bucks a gallon"

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a slogan, but instead, how about a tag cloud?

[image: faux tag cloud]

It lets people know *exactly* what the site is about, paired with one of the slogans here about Q&A it'd be a pretty complete picture.

This could be done so it fits in with Jin's design for the site. Maybe the folks at Stackapps could come up with a way to generate a proper cloud; this one is just a mockup.

---

Edit: Here's the tag cloud again, with freiheit's changes.

[image: faux tag cloud v2]

Comment: I like this concept. Not sure if there's room for it on the bottle along with Night (meta) + Day art + URL.

Comment: It's too much tag cloud ... Excluding frugal, regional, mechanical, product-rec and equipment would be good (off-putting, confusing out of context, or tags we need to kill) would help a bit...

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to be critical without having any better answer to propose, but I find [the current suggestions](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/who-wants-water-bottles-who-has-a-catchy-tagline/442#442) yuck.

The current suggestions try to be clever but aren't.

I suggest that if we can't be clever then at least be plain.

- Bicycles - your questions answered
- A web site for Q+A about bicycles
- Answering your questions about bicycles

I like the tag cloud except that it's not (it's bigger than) a tag line.

See also [One short paragraph that describes this site](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/416/one-short-paragraph-that-describes-this-site) for other more or less succinct descriptions of the site.

Comment: Maybe "Bicycles SE - your questions answered"? Other than that I believe the first one is concise and right on the money.

Answer (score 4):

Just letting you know I submitted a final design for bottles to Specialized last week.

The bottles will look something like this:

[image]

I'm waiting on a mock-up and timeline for delivery. I'll let you know as soon as they're available.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to beat [Velominati Rule #5](http://www.velominati.com/blog/the-rules/#5) for succinct catchiness.

Comment: If I could +1 this twenty times, I would.

Comment: There are some other apropos ones there as well. "Rule #3 / Guide the uninitiated." "Rule #4 / It’s all about the bike." "Rule #10 / It never gets easier, you just go faster."

Answer (score 2):

It's not too late to throw another tagline into the ring or add one to this answer that I did not include.

The tentative finalists:

- **Hydration** (tag, maybe with a cursor hover box: *X Followers, subscribe, rss, description, etc.*)
- **BRAIN GREASE**
- **A bike lane for your brain.**
- **The cycling solution.**
- **Bicycles: The answer to so many questions.**

Edit this post! Add more taglines! I'll get a final list up on Friday and we'll have a winner next week.

Comment: +1 for [tag:hydration] styled like one of our tags (with or without the hover box)

Answer (score 2):

## **Bicycles.SE Q&A**

### **We don't spin our wheels answering your questions.**

Answer (score 1):

### "We know bicycles"

(pulling back in [my old elevator pitch / tagline suggestion](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline/146#146) from October)

Comment: Not sure that everyone will feel welcomed by 'we know best' sentiment. That would be -1 if I was to be mean enough to vote!

Comment: @ʍǝɥʇɐɯ On meta it's appropriate to downvote based on disagreement.  I won't be offended in the slightest if you disagree.  See the [FAQ on meta voting](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences)

Answer (score 1):

Can we have a play with 'solved' or 'solution' (rather than question and answer)?

I am not there yet on this meme but I think that something better than this could work in the tagline:

**'...solved by cycling**'

Note that '...by cycling' has the 'bicycle' soundalike but is about the act of cycling. This idea is not there yet, but the play on water being a solution is getting there for the bottle:

**Bicycles SE**

**'the cycling solution'**

or a little less terse:

**'the refreshing cycling solution'**

Thinking on my pedals here, I also think that the original 'overflow' idea could be worked into the tagline as an in-joke, e.g:

**Bicycles SE**

**'overflowing with cycling solutions'**

Please brainstorm with the meme! Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

Over the years there have been very few compelling water bottles for retail sale. I don't know why they have to be so boring! At the retail level this is a problem when people ask for one specifically and you show them the 'efforts' on sale for them to say no thanks! They have a £5 burning in their pocket but there is nothing that just grabs them. Consequently I believe that a series of well designed water bottles will be well received.

Hence my suggestion is for a bike bottle design competition. With the other competition on hold, we might be able to run with something of global appeal. We could put down a few pointers of what we are looking for as well as a few technical pointers - a limit on the colours, whether those colours can include hi-viz and printing accuracy.

We don't need to tie the design down to anything to do with bicycles.se except that will have to appear in the design somewhere. Also the artwork can be whatever, not anything to do with the site graphics.

Things that I would like to see get entered might include:

- Technical use of the design, e.g. ml/pint/mouthfuls measurements on the side, a chain stretch measurement guide, miles to km ready reckoner.
- 'Pro-bike' (anti-car) slogans - '100% unleaded high octane water'/'one less car'
- 'Retro passion' - the designer for the film TRON2 came up with the 2011 HRT F1 car, using 'retro' checkered flag designs and silly slogans (because the HRT team had no sponsors)
- 'Fish tank' - the womens lib 'fish on a bicycle' idea
- 'What car would Jesus drive?' (with some 'find answers to this on bikes.se' quip)
- 'Adbusters' subvertising of well known slogans, e.g. 'just ride it!'
- Things That Sell. 'I [heart] my bike'
- 'Cyclist on board'

To see what I mean by rubbish bike bottle designs (no offence to Wiggle, they are just representative): http://www.wiggle.co.uk/cycle/water-bottles/

You don't even get 'Cafe de Colombia'/'Coke' and other Tour de France bottle designs nowadays.

We could spam every single bike/green/education org on the planet with such a competition, maybe even have a javascript app to render a flat design onto a bottle as part of the entry form. Entrants could have a reasonable prize given to them if they win. We could have the vote online to get the finalists sorted out with an invited panel of do-gooder celebrity cyclists having the final say. A gold/silver/bronze + public choice to get four designs sorted, the idea being to make these into a commercial success. (There *is* a market for some quality bottles.)